# Find and rename files with no extension?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, rename

So, I've got a bunch of files with no extension.  I want to write a windows batch script that will:

1. Find files with no extension (in a specified folder)
2. Add .bla to the end of the file name

I'm such a windows batch script noob I don't even know where to start.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For windows batch files, this will rename only files with no extension to the .bla extension:

```
rename *. *.bla
```

Notice the first argument is a star and a dot: *.

The second argument is: *.bla

The start dot (*.) combination represents files with no extensions in this context.

Before:

```
06/21/2009  11:57 PM                 6 test
06/21/2009  11:57 PM                 7 test.exe
06/21/2009  11:57 PM                 7 test2
```

After:

```
06/21/2009  11:57 PM                 6 test.bla
06/21/2009  11:57 PM                 7 test.exe
06/21/2009  11:57 PM                 7 test2.bla
```

Additional note: The opposite commandline would rename all .bla files into no extension files.

**EDIT**:

For recursively renaming files with no extension across subdirectories (doesn't support spaces in paths):

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%i in ('dir /b/s/A-d') DO (
  if "%%~xi" == "" rename "%%~fi" "%%~ni.bla"
)
```

**EDIT2:**

For recursively renaming files with no extension across subdirectories (supports spaces in path):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('dir /b/s/A-d') DO (
  if "%%~xi" == "" rename "%%~fi" "%%~ni.bla"
)
```

Comment: I considered that, but there isn't even a dot at the end of the name... will this still work?

Comment: Also, how would I include subfolders?

Comment: @Alan - Yes it will work, and how many subfolders are we talking about?

Comment: I tested it, start dot represents files with no extensions.

Comment: @JFV Just one level deep, but a bunch of them.

Comment: Then just use the same syntax, but define the new directory:
ren *. *.bla
ren <path to new dir>\*. *.bla

Comment: Rather, there are a bunch of folders one level deep...so i need to figure out something that will process them all.  Hmmm...

Comment: In case you're still interested... I've done an edit to recursively do that across all subfolders.

Comment: Please could you suggest a command for linux for the same kind of a problem?

Answer (score 7):

Here's another possible command for renaming files with no extensions recursively (assuming that **file paths don't contain spaces**):

```
for /f %i in ('dir *. /b /s /a-d') do rename "%~fi" "%~ni.bla"
```

Batch version (with doubled `%`):

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir *. /b /s /a-d') do (
   rename "%%~fi" "%%~ni.bla"
)
```

**If file or folder names contain spaces**, use this command instead:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ('dir *. /b /s /a-d') do rename "%~fi" "%~ni.bla"
```

Batch version:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('dir *. /b /s /a-d') do (
   rename "%%~fi" "%%~ni.bla"
)
```

---

**Edit:** here's even shorter one-liner that supports spaces in paths:

```
for /r %i in (*.) do ren "%~fi" "%~ni.bla"
```

Batch version:

```
@for /r %%i in (*.) do ren "%%~fi" "%%~ni.bla"
```

Answer (score 4):

to do this in subdirectories use this:

```
 for /f %a in ('dir /b /ad /s') do rename %a\*. *.bla
```

if you are using this in a batch file, you need to double the '%'

```
 for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad /s') do rename %%a\*. *.bla
```

**edit:**

and if you have spaces in your directory names, you can try this (batch version):

```
 for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /ad /s') do rename "%%a\*." "*.bla"
```

Comment: Minor issue here - not working for directories with spaces...otherwise looking good