# Batch rename file extensions, including subdirectories

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm renaming empty file extensions with this command:

```
rename *. *.bla
```

However, I have a folder with hundreds of such subfolders, and this command requires me to manually navigate to each subfolder and run it.

Is there a command that I can run from just one upper level folder that will include all the files in the subfolders?

Comment: /me think it belongs here too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('dir /b/s/A-d') DO (
  if "%%~xi" == "" rename "%%~fi" "%%~ni.bla"
)
```

Thanks @Wadih M. [Find and rename files with no extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025410/find-and-rename-files-with-no-extention)

Answer (score 7):

```
for /r c:\path\ %G in (*.) do ren "%G" *.bla
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this and many more things with the Perl module [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html).

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $extension = 'bla';
my $directory = '/tmp/test';

print "Files renamed:\n";
find( \&wanted, $directory );

sub wanted {
    return if /\./;
    return unless -f $File::Find::name;

    if ( rename( $File::Find::name, "$File::Find::name.$extension" ) ) {
        print "    $File::Find::name -> $File::Find::name.$extension\n";
    }
    else {
        print "    Error: $! - $File::Find::name\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this will allow you to enter dirs with spaces in the names. (note the double % is for batch files, use a single % for command lines.)

```
 for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /ad /s') do rename "%%a\*." "*.bla"
```

Comment: Giving me not recognizes as internal or external command error.  Using single % for command line test.  Seems pretty close, but it's just not quite doing it.

Comment: you are using the single % for both the for loop and the rename?

Comment: Correct.  Any luck on your end?

Comment: yes, it is working fine. can you copy/paste the command you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for /R c:\temp %I in (*. ) DO Echo rename %I "%~nI.bla"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` to iterate over subdirectories:

```
for /d %x in (*) do pushd %x & ren *. *.bla & popd
```

When using it from a batch file you would need to double the `%` signs:

```
for /d %%x in (*) do pushd %%x & ren *. *.bla & popd
```

Comment: so will this start in the current directory if issued from the command line?  (just don't want to accidentally spill into the rest of the drive)

Comment: Yes. If you need it to be in a fixed directory, you can alter the wildcard in the parentheses to something like for /d %x in (%userprofile%\foo\*) do ...

Answer (score 0):

Using find and xargs and basename would make the expression easier to read

Prepare a rename shell script like this (corrected to handle multiple files)

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 3 ] 
then
    echo "usage: rename.sh sufold sufnew file1 (file2 file3 ...) "
    exit
fi

sufold=$1
sufnew=$2
shift
shift

for f in $*
do
  echo "to mv " $f `dirname $f`"/"`basename $f $sufold`$sufnew
  mv $f `dirname $f`"/"`basename $f $sufold`$sufnew
done
```

Then you could invoke that to each file matched your criteria, including recursive folder search by find command

```
find . -name "*." | xargs rename.sh "." ".bla"
```

A more common sample

```
find . -name "*.htm" | xargs rename.sh ".htm" ".html"
```