# DOS Batch Rename Files

Tags: batch-file, dos, file-rename, zero-pad

I have a large set files with names structured `string_int_int_int_string.extension`, and would like to batch rename them with left zero padding to 7 digits on the second int.

Example: rename `stringA_1_2_3_stringB.jpg` to `stringA_1_0000002_3_stringB.jpg`.

I've seen some helpful posts [here](https://superuser.com/questions/403183/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-multiple-folders-with-1-command/403185#403185), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025470/batch-rename-file-extensions-including-subdirectories), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417979/batch-rename-sequential-files-by-padding-with-zeroes) but haven't quite done it.

Here is what I have so far (not working, of course):

```
dir /b *.* >temp.txt

for /f "tokens=%%1,%%2,%%3,%%4,%%5 delims=_" %x in (temp.txt) do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set PAD=000000%%k
    set PAD=!PAD:~7!
    ren "%%i_%%j_%%k_%%l_%%m" %%i_%%j_%PAD%_%%l_%%m
)
```

I specifically want to do this with a batch file, not some other language or tool. (I'm aware of the various renaming tools out there.)

Any help is most welcome!

Comment: Do you want to do this SomeName_1_2_3_SomeName to SomeName_1_0000002_3_SomeName?

Comment: Exactly. I'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
dir /b *.* >temp.txt
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=_" %%a in (temp.txt) do (
   set PAD=000000%%c
   set PAD=!PAD:~-7!
   ren "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e"  "%%a_%%b_!PAD!_%%d_%%e"
)
```

Comment: @user1205577: Insert an ECHO before the REN and report what is shown. Also, check that file names have the indicated format.

Comment: @user1205577: DON'T DELETE older comments, because answers for them looks somewhat incoherent... Please, report if my solution correctly works (your deleted comment indicate that it does not, and you never clear this point).  :(

Answer (score 0):

I use FINDSTR to filter out file names that don't match the specified pattern. A total of 4 tokens are needed - the first 3, followed by the rest of the file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=_" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d * ^|findstr /r "^[^_]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[^_]"'
) do (
  set "mid=%%C"
  set "pad=0000000%%C"
  set "start=%%A_%%B"
  set "end=%%D"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo ren "!start!_!mid!_!end!" "!start!_!pad:~-7!_!end!"
  endlocal
)
```