# Rename files having no extension

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, cmd

How can we rename all files in a folder having no extension at all to ".something"?

I have tried `ren *.* *.jpeg` and few more but nothing working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and rename files with no extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025410/find-and-rename-files-with-no-extension)

Answer (score 17):

Asterisk `*` matches any extension. You want to match *no* extension, so don't supply one. Both of the below variants will do in your case:

- `ren *  *.jpeg`
- `ren *. *.jpeg`

NOTE: you may read [here](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) about the peculiarities of using `*` and `*.` with the `ren` command.

---

The above only works in Windows [Command shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands#command-line-shells) (cmd). PowerShell's *wildcards* work differently, and mostly don't do anything special with extensions. What's more, batch renaming in PowerShell works differently. So:

```
dir -Filter "*." -File | ren -NewName { $_.name -replace "$", ".jpeg" }
```

Comment: This gave this error for me: ren : Cannot rename because item at '*.' does not exist.

Comment: @EBGreen: correct, that only works with cmd. The PowerShell version is more involved, see edit. (Although there may be a more elegant way.)

Comment: You explained very well , as earlier i was trying to run it through powershell.. by using simple cmd 'ren ......' command... & That's why it didn't worked.... Cool

Answer (score 4):

"rename *. *.jpg"  weirdly will bring up "The syntax of the command is incorrect." if there are no files without extensions in the location. I thought the command stopped working at first! So just letting people know if they have the same thing come up.

Answer (score 2):

This is tested and works for me:

```
ls -file | ?{$_.extension -eq ''} | %{ren $_ ($_.name + '.jpeg')}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation:

```
dir -filter *. -file | rename-item -NewName {"$($_.name)`.jpg"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did everything correct but instead of `*.*` you ought to use `*.` as `*.*` searches for all files with all extensions but the former searches for all files with no extension and that is what you want. So here is your code:

```
rename *. *.something
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025414/4427870) answer for further help.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file "*." | rename-item -NewName {"{0}.something" -f $_.fullname}
```

Comment: This is too hard to try... I just wanted a simple command...&#128516; if you understand, but thanks for the help

Comment: its a really command PowerShell, others proposition base on alias :)

Comment: this was great for Powershell, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me as simple as `ren * *.jpeg` worked.

Comment: this gave an invalid path for me

Comment: Double-checked: renaming of 3 files with no extension in Windows cmd did the job.

Comment: Aaah...my mistake, I assumed powershell. You are correct that it will add the .jpeg to all the files. ***All the files*** including files with an extension.

Comment: Yeah, to give to only without extension would be ren *. *.jpeg